# Does there exist a 3-dimensional subspace of real functions consisting only of monotone functions?

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis

This is [Exercise 1.O](http://books.google.com/books?id=Cqk5AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA13#v=onepage&q&f=false) from the book 
Van Rooij, Schikhof: **A Second Course on Real Functions**.

> The set of the monotone functions on $[0,1]$ contains all polynomial
>   functions of degree $\le 1$. These form a two-dimensional vector space. Does the set of
>   all monotone functions contain a three-dimensional vector space?

Comment: Maybe it's worth mentioning that if we solve this problem for monotone functions $[0,1]\to\mathbb R$, the same must be true for any closed interval. This can be used to answer the same question for monotone functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, since $\mathbb R=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty [-n,n]$.

Comment: Yes that's a nice extension although your last step ($\mathbb{R} = \cup \dotsc$) then still needs a little bit more explanation, since a single relation must work for *all* intervals.

Comment: I was probably too hasty to write the above comment @WimC; Later I'll try to teg back to the question whether some argument along these lines can be done to get the result for $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$ instead of $\mathbb R^{[0,1]}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $V$ is a vector space of monotone functions and $f_1, f_2, f_3 \in V$ then $\left(f_i(0), f_i(1)\right) \in \mathbb{R^2}$ are three vectors in a two-dimensional space and therefore dependent. That means that there is a non-trivial linear combination of $f_1, f_2, f_3$ that vanishes at $0$ and $1$ and because it is also monotone, it is identically zero. So any three elements of $V$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: why is a function which is monotone and vanishes at 0 and 1 identically zero?

Comment: @Mariano The question was formulated for functions $[0,1]\to\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 12):

Somewhat simpler: Let $V$ be a $3$-dimensional vector space of monotone functions.  Consider any linearly independent $f_1,f_2 \in V$.  Then $g = (f_2(1) - f_2(0)) f_1 - (f_1(1) - f_1(0)) f_2 \in V$ has 
$g(0) = g(1)$, so since $g$ is monotone it must be constant.
Moreover since $f_1$ and $f_2$ are linearly independent, $g \ne 0$.  Thus the constant function $1 \in V$.  But if $V$ is $3$-dimensional, it has a basis that contains $1$, and we just showed this is impossible because $1$ is in the span of the other two basis elements.

EDIT: another way to say this. Suppose $f_1$, $f_2$, $f_3$ are linearly independent members of $V$.  We may assume $f_2$ is not a scalar multiple of $1$.  Then $1 = a f_1 + b f_2 = c f_2 + d f_3$ for some scalars $a,b,c,d$, with $a \ne 0$.  So $a f_1 + (b-c) f_2 - d f_3 = 0$, contradicting  linear independence.

Comment: Nice! ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 7):

$\newcommand{\Zobr}[3]{{#1}\colon{#2}\to{#3}}\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}\newcommand{\intrv}[2]{[{#1},{#2}]}$
**Lemma.** Let $\Zobr{f,g}{\intrv01}{\R}$ be functions such that $f(0)=g(0)=0$ and the function $af(x)+bg(x)$ is monotone for any $a,b\in R$.
Then $f=0$ or $g=cf$ for some constant $c\in\R$.

*Proof.* Let $f\ne 0$. Let us denote the space consisting of all linear combinations of $f$ and $g$ by $V$. We assume that all functions in $V$ are monotone.

W.l.o.g we can assume that $f$ is non-decreasing. (Otherwise we can use the same proof for $-f$.)

Let us take an $x_0>0$ such that $f(x_0)>0$.

Put
\begin{align*}
c&:=\frac{g(x_0)}{f(x_0)}\\
h(x)&:=g(x)-cf(x)
\end{align*}
We have $h(0)=h(x_0)=0$, which implies $h(t)=0$ for every $t\in\intrv0{x_0}$. (Since $h$ is monotone.)

a) If $h=0$ then $g=cf$.

b) Suppose that $h\ne 0$. Then there exists a point $y_0$ such that $h(y_0)\ne 0$. We know that $y_0\notin\intrv0{x_0}$

This implies $0<x_0<y_0$. We have
\begin{align*}
0&=f(0)<f(x_0)\le f(y_0)\\
0&=h(0)=h(x_0)\ne h(y_0)
\end{align*}
W.l.o.g we may assume $h(y_0)>0$. (Otherwise we can work with $-h$.)

b.1) Suppose that $f(x_0)=f(y_0)$ and define $h_1=f-h$. Clearly $h_1\in V$, but
$$0<h_1(x_0)=f(x_0)>h_1(y_1)=f(x_0)-h(y_0),$$
so $h_1$ is not monotone.

b.2) Now suppose that $f(x_0)<f(y_0)$.

In this case we define
$$h_1:=f-2h\frac{f(y_0)-f(x_0)}{h(y_0)}.$$
Clearly $h_1\in V$. We have
$$h_1(0)=0<h_1(x_0)=f(x_0) > h_1(y_0)=f(y_0)-2[f(y_0)-f(x_0)]=f(x_0)-[f(y_0)-f(x_0)].$$
So the function $h_1$ is not monotone.
$\hspace{2cm}\square$

The basic idea of the proof of this lemma is that if we have function which look similarly to the functions in the following picture, we can find a linear combination, which is not monotone.

[image: f and h]

---

**Corollary.**
If $\Zobr{f,g}{\intrv01}{\R}$ are functions such that the function $af+bg$ is monotone for any $a,b\in\R$, then $f(x)=c$ for some constant $c\in\R$
or $g(x)=cf(x)+d$ for some constants $c,d\in\R$.

*Proof.*
We apply the above lemma to the functions $f_1(x)=f(x)-f(0)$ and $g_1(x)=g(x)-g(0)$. $\hspace{2cm}\square$

---

The claim of the exercise follows from this corollary. Indeed, suppose that $V$ is a subspace of $\R^{\intrv01}$ which contains only monotone functions. We can assume that $V$ contains all constant functions, since adding a constant function does not influence monotonicity. The corollary says that if we take two linearly independent functions $1,f\in V$, then all remanding functions in $V$ are linear combinations of $1$ and $f$.

---

*Remark.* The above proof can be adapted without much effort to
functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ (instead of $[0,1]\to\mathbb
R$). We just need to add one more case $y_0<0<x_0$ to our lemma. (It
is sufficient to deal only with $x_0>0$, since the case $x_0<0$ is
symmetric.)

Comment: can u tell me why is $h(x_0)=0$ in the first proof ?

Comment: i think $c$ is $ \frac {f(x_0)} {g(x_0)}$

Comment: I've corrected the definition of $h(x)$; it should be $h(x)=g(x)-cf(x)$. Thanks for noticing this, @Ananda.

Comment: Can i post this problem on my blog ? Let me know if the norms of MSE allows to do so ?

Comment: @Ananda I don't see any problem with that. Moreover, the problem is taken from a book, it was not my own invention. Perhaps you can post link to your blog here, if you do so.